# How to search for data divided by backslash using regular expressions in Python

Tags: python, regex, arcgis, backslash, arcpy

I am trying to list a part of data divided by single backslash. The part is only a six digit number. The reason why I need to quote backslashes is that I will use this code for more files, which might include other six (and more) digit numbers in the group of data.

Here is an example of the code:

```
>>> layer = arcpy.mapping.Layer("J:\abcd\blabla.lyr")
>>> print layer.dataSource
C:\Users\416938\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.0\ArcCatalog\...
>>> result = re.search (r'([a-z]{1}[0-9]{6})', text)
>>> result.group(0)
u'416938'
```

But I would like to include the backslashes like this (obviously this code wouldn't work):

```
re.search (r'(\[0-9] {6}\)', text)
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: provide an example along with expected output.

Comment: Is `{6}` related to the whitespace or the number class?

Comment: If you want relevant help, not just *any*, please update your question with sample strings and specify what you need to match in them.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Thanks, I have updated it. Your code works! Thank you.

Comment: @wenzul `{6}` is related to the number class

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://regex101.com/r/pI9hS2/2) or [this](https://regex101.com/r/pI9hS2/3) works for you?

Comment: @stribizhev The second link. I've tried it on other .lyr files and it works better that the other one.

Comment: @user2441860: Then I have posted an answer, please check. Let me know if you need more explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code you can use to *extract 6-digit number that is a whole word*:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'\b[0-9]{6}\b')
test_str = ur"C:\\Users\\416938\\AppData\\Roaming\\ESRI\\Desktop10.0\\ArcCatalog"
match = re.search(p, test_str)
if match:
    print(match.group(0))
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/UWEaJr)

Note that [`\b` - a word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) - matches at the following positions:

> - Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
> - After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
> - Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

If you want to match a 6-digit sequence inside `\...\` you can use

```
(?<=\\)[0-9]{6}(?=\\)
```

Or if you want to match a 6-digit sequence not enclosed with other digits (e.g. between letters), use this regex:

```
(?<!\d)[0-9]{6}(?!\d)
```

It contains 2 look-arounds. `(?<!\d)` makes sure there is no digit before the the 6-digit sequence and `(?!\d)` makes sure there is no digit after it.

Comment: Thank you for explaining :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the backslashes :

```
re.search (r'(\\[0-9] {6}\\)', text)
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer is also useful.

Answer (score 0):

If the windows path will always have the given structure `C:\Users\[0-9]{6}\...` - here we go without complicated escaped regex syntax:

```
>>> text = r"C:\Users\416938\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.0\ArcCatalog"
>>> match = text.split("\\")[2]  # split at \ and grad third element
'416938'
>>> if match.isdigit() and len(match) == 6:  # check for digit and length 6
...
```